# How to quit python script in gdb-python?

Tags: python-2.7, gdb-python

I am writing a python(v2.7) script in GDB(v7.5.1-0.7.29). I want to quit the python script when certain condition got false. But i do not want to quit GDB. I tried using sys.exit(), exit() and quit(), but in those case they also quit GDB. Is there any way to just quit the python script but not the gdb. Like ctrl + c command but i want this happend only when a certain condition got false.

Answer (score 0):

CTRL+D does that

```
 (gdb) pi
 >>>        [Press CTRL+D] 
 (gdb)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to raise an exception. Question is what exception to raise; whether you provide code to catch it and whether you want traceback to be printed or not.

If you don't mind traceback to be printed you can `raise KeyboardInterrupt`. But I presume you want graceful exit without traceback.

If you are writing code for class that integrates into GDB command then you can `raise gdb.GdbError`. It will be consumed by the code implementing command class and no traceback is printed.

If you are writing a script that is executed by sourcing it then you have to embed your whole script into `try` / `except` and catch exception you are raising. In fact, calling `exit()` also simply raises exception `SystemExit`, so you may write your script as:

```py
try:
    some code
    if some_condition:
        exit()
    some more code
except SystemExit:
    pass
```